# OSPF LSA checksum error

Tags: ospf

I have a Centos 5 box running quagga 0.98.2 which is flooding `ospfd.log` with:

```
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 58d5.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 63bf.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 63bf.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 63bf.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 6ab1.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 6dab.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 6fa7.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 6fa7.
OSPF: Link State Update: LSA checksum error 2a32, 6fa7.
```

It has 20 neighbors and same error appears only on one of them which is on the same physical network.

My question is what can cause LSA checksum errors and how to identify which host is sending broken LSA updates?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Are all neighbors Quagga boxes as well or cisco/juniper/etc?  Could be any number of things:

1. Bad interface on one of the neighbors
2. Bad interface on switch facing one of neighbors on this network
3. Misbehaving ospfd process on one of the quagga boxes
4. Bug in Quagga?
5. Bug in version of code running on actual router hardware (if one of your neighbors is not a Quagga box)

Comment: They are all running a bit outdated quagga but only two of them are experiencing LSA checksum errors. I've checked physical ports and there are no CRC or other errors. Is there is a way of checking who sends LSAs with wrong checksums ? Both boxes are showing same LSA checksum error 2a32 in ospfd.log

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's very rare quagga bug which has been fixed in version 0.99.13

I will try upgrading and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Hi Kobazik, thanks for the update... Please be sure to accept this answer if it actually solves the problem.